# alamofire 401 response on https request, (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, alamofire

I have a ios(swift) project that uses alamofire for request to the server.

I get 401 responses when call api with "https" url but when use "http" it's work fine and in postman with the same header and url I get result for both https and http and I'm sure the problem is in app not api.

**info.plist:**
[image]

and api Caller:

```
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 300
    self.alamoFire = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
self.alamoFire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.GetRequestsHeader)
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseJSON
                { (response) in
                    if (response.response?.statusCode == 401){
                        DataStorage().save(key: DataStorageEnum.Session.rawValue, value: "")
                    }
                    else if let session = response.response?.allHeaderFields[RequestsHeaderEnum.FSession.rawValue] as? String {
                        DataStorage().save(key: DataStorageEnum.Session.rawValue, value: session)
                    }
                    switch response.result
                    {
                    case .success:
                        if let jsonData = response.data
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                returnValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(type(of: returnValue), from: jsonData)
                                complition(returnValue)
                            }
                            catch let error
                            {
                                self._Logger.Log(errorMessage: error.localizedDescription, fileName: #file, functionName: #function, lineNumber: String(#line))
                                complition(returnValue)
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self._Logger.Log(errorMessage: error.localizedDescription, fileName: #file, functionName: #function, lineNumber: String(#line))
                        complition(returnValue)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: 401 is "unauthorized". You need to figure out what is different from you app's request and the postman request so that the server says that.

Comment: The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Comment: I checked my header filed many times, it's true I'm sure about that because if it wasn't true http does not work.